# Issue with ngShow

Tags: angularjs

I have following problem with ngShow. I receive response as a jSON from $http.get
and construct several DOM elements using ngRepeat. All this working properly. From my controller a just apply:

```
    $http.get(requestUrl).success(function (data) {
        $scope.results = data.results;
    });
```

data.results is a object like this:

```
{ 
   "someProp": ["item1", "item2", "item3"],
   "someProp1": ["item1", "item2", "item3"]
}
```

From my template I try to use ngShow like this:

```
<table ng-show="Object.keys(results).length > 0">
```

and like this:

```
<table ng-show="Object.keys($scope.results).length > 0">
```

With no luck.

```
<table ng-show="true">
```

and

```
<table ng-show="false">
```

working properly.

So it seems that the problem is in the expression. I would be very grateful for any help.

Comment: `ng-show` expects an [angular expression](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression), so without doublechecking you can't assume that every *normal* javascript function will just work.

Comment: wrap `Object.keys(results).length` in a function instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It does not evaluate the `Object.keys` function inside of the expression as it is not actually located on the scope.  One way you can get around this is by assigning the `Object` to the scope.

```
$scope.Object = Object;
```

and inside your view

```
<div ng-show="Object.keys(results).length > 0">
    {{Object.keys(results).length}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I've been scratching my head for a while why this didn't work.

Comment: where do you set $scope.Object = Object;
I got error??
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27311331/how-to-get-the-length-of-a-map-in-angularjs-ng-show

Answer (score 2):

Ng Show needs an instruction, you have to surround it with simple quotes

```
<table ng-show="'Object.keys(results).length > 0'">
```

Comment: Can't find it anywhere in the docs. However, it works indeed.

Answer (score 0):

You are storing `data.results` to `$scope.results`. Hence your scope variable will not have results. If you want to check for `results`, then use the following.

```
$http.get(requestUrl).success(function (data) {
        $scope.backEndJson = data;
});
```

Hence your HTML should have,

```
<table ng-show="backEndJson(results).length > 0">
```

BTW, we are not supposed to use `$scope` on the HTML side as `$scope` as all operations on the HTML side is assumed to be on the scope variable.

Comment: Process of substituting all angular expressions with scope variables is called interpolation

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<table ng-hide="angular.equals({}, results)">
```