# How to get the length of a map in angularjs ng-show?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

how can I get the length / size of a map in "ng-show"?

```
var map = { 
  "key1": "value1, 
  "key2": "value2, 
  "key3": "value2
}
```

### UPDATE 01

```
<button ng-show="Object.keys(map).length>0"></button>
```

or

```
<button ng-show="_.size(angular.copy(map)>0"></button>
```

### UPDATE 02

[Issue with ngShow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18490199/issue-with-ngshow)

where and how to set the $scope.Object = Object; ??

when I set that I got the following error:

> Error: [$parse:isecobj] Referencing Object in Angular expressions is
>   disallowed! Expression: Object.keys(selectedIdeas).length>0

Comment: This isn't specific to angularjs, it's a general javascript question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17335108/angularjs-counting-object-length

Comment: @vijay4vijju - it doesn't work on the ng-show. it works inside the js.